# Jquery inside PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

For some reason some Javascript/Jquery code does not work when placing it inside PHP.

```
<?php
  if (x > 0) { 
?>    

<script type="text/javascript">   
   alert("Hi!");   
   $("#fault_message_mail").hide();
</script>

<?php
  } else . . .
?>
```

In case `x>0`  it is executed only the Alert and not the hide method(I'd like to hide a div declared in some html code).

Why it is not executed? Is it prudent to use jQuery inside PHP?

I've been searching similar questions in Stack overflow, however I cannot find a positive answer.

Thank you

Comment: @ILIAS did you include jquery library ?

Comment: Do you mean `$x>0` instead of `x>0`?

Comment: But do you understand WHY you need to change the code? I get the idea that you were under the impression that the javascript would run the moment you see it in your PHP code.

Comment: so we will need a more information, paste relevant code. Also check console is there any other errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to inlude jQuery library if you have not included :

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```

and then you have to write you code inside ready function like this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   ("#fault_message_mail").hide();
});
```

and third thing is that you have written a wrong syntax here :

```
<?php   
  if (x>0){ ?>
      ^
```

it should be like this :

```
<?php   
  if ($x>0){ ?>
```

Answer (score 6):

You'll need to attach a handler something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   ("#fault_message_mail").hide();
});
```

or

```
$('#mybutton').click(function(){
   ("#fault_message_mail").hide();
});
```

Comment: Obviously, the DOM is not fully loaded when manipulating elements of the DOM. @ILIAS

Answer (score 1):

maybe the element is not in the dom, try the following

```
  if (x>0){ ?>

  <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(function ($) { // run on document.ready
          alert("Hi!");   
          $("#fault_message_mail").hide();
        });
    </script>
<?php }
```